# Struts 2 List Parameter Passing

Tags: list, jsp, struts2, integer

How do I pass a list of integers using the s:a href and param tags in Struts 2?

Example POJO:

```
private List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public List<Integer> getMyList() {
    return myList;
}

public void setMyList(List<Integer> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
}
```

Example JSP Page:

```
<s:url id="testUrl" action="testAction">
   <s:param name="myList" value="%{myList}" />
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{testUrl}">Test Link</s:a>
```

When I click on the "Test Link", the form submits the following for myList:

[1,+2,+3,+4,+5]

This results in Struts re-directing to the "input" page. This is not the desired behavior. Does anyone have any suggestions about how to pass a list of integers correctly using the Struts tags?

Comment: What is your desired url result?

Comment: Anything that a Struts 2 getter method can process. The recipient class has a method public void setMyList(List<Integer> myList) which is identical to the setter described in the question. Instead of setting the list, Struts redirects me to the "input" page.

Answer (score 0):

The param tag calls the toString on the list to put the parameter in the URL if I remember right. Therefore the action that should get the list only gets a string.

The setter on the next action needs to accept a string and in this setter you could split up the string, extract the numbers and fill a new list with that.

Comment: Yes, this is a reasonable workaround and I have used string parsing  in the past to handle this case. I was hoping that someone would have a way to natively handle Lists. For example, Struts 2 automatically handles date and integer types. I don't need to have a String and cast it into an integer. I can just declare an integer and Struts 2 handles the conversion of the String to integer.

Comment: Yes, the param interceptor handles this "magic". But it is only handling easy datastructures. With a list, it couldn't know what you put in there, would likely call toString on it and on the other side would then treat it as a list of strings. I guess you could extend the params interceptor if you wanted that functionality and then use that extended params interceptor instead of the default one from the default stack.

Comment: Another solution to what you're looking for might be storing the list in the user's session with help of the SessionAware interceptor - but from your question I don't know what the real idea behind passing those parameters is. Hope that helped :-)